# Would some step-by-step guides be relevant to the site?

Tags: discussion

Would posting a step-by-step guide for something, such as drawing resonating structures of a given compound or elucidating some beautiful revealing connections, where people often get stuck at, be relevant to the site?

I mean would be helpful to do something like that or would be unnecessary given the alternatives that one may have at hand, such as Google.

Comment: "making resonating structures of a given compound" what do you mean by this? Do you mean drawing them out using software? Or coming up with the resonance structures in the first place?

Comment: I edited to clarify further.

Comment: One possibility is to create a FAQ in the tag wiki that links to different (existing) answers on the topic.  Another would be to make some "canonical questions" (with authoritative answers that we can use as a duplicate target). "Step-by-step" anything is not great for Q+A as a whole because any answers should apply to one and only one highly particular question.